# The area bounded by the curve questions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What's the area bounded by the curve $f(x)=3x^3 - x^2 - 10x$ and $g(x)=-x^2+2x$

I solved for $f(x) = 0$ and get $-\frac{5}{3}$ , **$0$ , $2$**
and $g(x) = 0$ and get $0 , 2$

Solved $f(x) = g(x)$ I Found their third intersection when $x = -2$

The problem I've is how to solve the area with all these known intersections ?

Comment: have you graphed the functions?

Comment: I do see the the area I need is from -2 to 0 and 0 to 2, but I don't know how to solve for it

Comment: Use two integrals: $\int$ uppercurve - lower curve, with the bounds being the correct x value for the points of intersection.

Comment: So my integral from -2 to 0 should be f(x) - g(x) and 0 to 2 be g(x) - f(x) ?

Comment: user61618 yes indeed...you know what you're doing, right on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

We separate the integral into two integrals to find the area bounded by the two curves which intersect at $x = -2, x = 0, x = 2$: subtracting the upper curve from the lower curve.

$$\int_{-2}^0 (3x^3 - x^2 - 10 x - (-x^2 + 2x))\,dx + \int_{0}^2 (-x^2 + 2x - (3x^3 - x^2 - 10 x))\,dx$$

Simplifying gives us $$\int_{-2}^0 (3x^3 - 12x)\,dx + \int_{0}^2 (-3x^3 + 12x)\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks. I finally understand. my teacher made a mistake on the class which confused me.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: +1 for including such a nice graph along with your answer! I hope the OP appreciates it! Regards

Comment: How could you make that red spots? Did you use Maple? If so, please note me the codes. +